# Does this integral have a closed form solution?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, differential-calculus

Let $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^2$, $B_r(0)=\{x||x|\leq r\}$. Does the following function (denoted as $f(r)$) have a closed form expression?

$$f(r)=\int_{B_r(0)}\int_{B_r(0)}\ln|x-y|dxdy.$$

Comment: MSE is a right forum for such questions.

Comment: For $r=1$ Mathematica answers $-\frac{\pi ^2}{4}$.

Comment: A simple observation shows how $f(r)$ is related to $f(1)$.

Comment: Hi wanjie. I've attempted to correct some grammatical errors in your question. I think your question is a good one, and most of the solution has been given in the comments, but I agree with others that it is probably more suitable for [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/). MathOverflow is intended for questions about research-level mathematics, whereas Mathematics Stack Exchange is intended for more general mathematical questions such as this one.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: Dispite your claim, this is not so simple. In the general case the answer obtained with Mathematica is $\frac{1}{4} \pi ^2 r^4 (4 \log (r)-1) .$

Comment: @user64494 Make the simple substitution $x' = rx$, $y' = ry$. It's true that one does not get a straightforward scaling relation, but the result is simply that there is an extra $\log(r)$ term as seen in the general answer.

Comment: To compute $f(1)$ just note that the inner integral yields $v$,  the radial solution of $\Delta v=2\pi$ in the unit ball with $v(0)=-\pi/2$. Then $v/2\pi=\rho^2/4-1/4$.